# Unable to Connect Polkadot.js Apps to Dockerized Aleph-nodes in WSL2

Tags: docker, wsl-2, substrate, polkadot, polkadot-js

I am using WSL2 to run multiple [Aleph](https://stackoverflow.com)nodes within Docker containers for network testing purposes. The network appears to start successfully based on the logs. However, I am encountering issues when trying to connect to these nodes using https://polkadot.js.org/apps/.

The general process for starting the network involves the following steps:

```
#Build the Aleph-node with the following command:
cargo build --release

#Clean up the existing data directory:
rm -rf ./docker/data

#Build the Docker image with the specified Dockerfile:
docker build --tag aleph-node:latest -f ./docker/Dockerfile .

#Execute the script to run the consensus process:
.github/scripts/run_consensus.sh
```

When attempting to connect to a `local node`, I receive the message `"Waiting to establish a connection with the remote endpoint,"` and the connection does not proceed.

If I try to use `ws://0.0.0.0:9944` in the `"Custom"` connection option, I encounter the following error message: `"Failed to construct 'WebSocket': An insecure WebSocket connection may not be initiated from a page loaded over HTTPS."`

When using `wss://0.0.0.0:9944` in the `"Custom"` option, I still receive the message `"Waiting to establish a connection with the remote endpoint."`

In my `docker-compose.yml`, I have configured the nodes to use `network_mode: host`, and I have set the environment variable `DISCOVER_LOCAL=true`.

Additionally, I have specified the following in my `Dockerfile`: `EXPOSE 30333 30343 9944`.

It's worth noting that I don't encounter any connectivity issues when using these settings on native Ubuntu/macOS (as reported by my colleagues).

Can someone please help me understand how to properly configure the WebSocket connection and resolve this issue specifically in the context of WSL2?

PS. I used both a browser running on Windows 11 and a browser running within WSL2 (Ubuntu), and experienced the same non-functional behavior.